How to find reason(s) for massive packet drops, between physical interface and virtual bridge?
I have two Proxmox hosts connected to one switch. Both Proxmox hosts have identical hardware, and are connected to the switch using LACP with two links in a bond.
The WAN connection is connected to the Cisco C3850 through an access port on VLAN 2100.
On the Proxmox hosts are VMs deployed to provide Internet access and services. In this case, an OPNsense appliance with vmbr0 passed-through, doing the Inter-VLAN routing between VLAN 3 (Trusted Devices) and VLAN 2100 (WAN).
I am encountering the following issue.
Sometimes when using voice services or apps, and I am talking, people can still hear me, but I can't hear them at all anymore. It starts stuttering, they sound like a robot, and I see a massive packet loss inside OPNsense.
(I ordered a 2nd known-good WAN circuit because I thought the first WAN circuit was faulty, but it proved to be not, when I connected a physical host to the WAN circuit. So same issue with new WAN as well.)
It occurs randomly in such heavy bursts, but there is always some sort of "noise" with continuous packet drops.
I checked the Cisco switch statistics, and the bond0 statistics on Proxmox, and they are fine. ethtool -S on driver level also doesn't indicate any drops. But in the Linux network stack itself, enp7s0 has some drops, enp8s0 has none, the bond0 has a few, and vmbr0 has massive!
During a download it increases to 10,000 packet drops per second.
How can I troubleshoot this issue?
When moving the VM to the other host, the issue persists. It also occurs with OpenWrt VM instead of OPNsense, so not limited to the VM.  With physical appliances, like physical OPNsense, everything is fine, even with a bond connected.
The hardware is quite powerful with server grade Gigabyte MC12 motherboard and Ryzen 5900X on both machines, both using 64GB ECC memory and almost no load.
What might be the issue here?
I am out of ideas now, as I am considering the physical network to be stable.
Now following some stats of my Proxmox machine with 20 hours of uptime.
ip -s link show dev on all network devices.
enp7s0
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether d8:5e:d3:69:d2:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
RX:  bytes packets errors dropped  missed   mcast           
 575842237 5271571      0   13401       0 4036793 
TX:  bytes packets errors dropped carrier collsns           
   1590672   12828      0       0       0       0

bond0
14: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master vmbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether d8:5e:d3:69:d2:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
RX:  bytes  packets errors dropped  missed   mcast           
8648538202 36785886      0   26848       0 8083302 
TX:  bytes  packets errors dropped carrier collsns           
6548328868 25839452      0       0       0       0 

vmbr0
15: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:5e:d3:69:d2:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX:  bytes  packets errors dropped  missed   mcast           
    9229290098 33579578      0 2226906       0 3499408 
    TX:  bytes  packets errors dropped carrier collsns           
    4890727799 23396693      0       0       0       0 


Just a note, you should not virtualize a software firewall, this is an unsecure and bad idea. I'm telling this, because this firewall is not able to protect it's host in a good manner. Any hardware or software bug, regarding that network connection will bypass the firewall and directly attack the proxmox host. I strongly recommend to outsource the software firewall to a dedicated hardware.
